# 2 or more elements in one 2D array's space JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm working on a project which requires putting 2 or more strings in one space in a 2D array. For example: from index i=0, j=0, store 4,5,6, and 7 in that particular space. 
I was thinking about using multidimensional array, but the problem is for the second array, the size (length) is not defined (in this case I use List or ArrayList). 
So the question is is there any array class/method to do this, or if I was to use ArrayList in a 2D String normal array, how would I create/add/print each String in that ArrayList

Comment: Perhaps could you visualize your example for easier understanding by editing your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, there's actually no such thing as a "multidimensional array", a two-dimensional array is an array of arrays, higher dimensions, arrays of arrays of arrays etc.  The only thing limiting the arrays to be the same size is that you initialize them as such. So you could easily store the information you wanted in a `string[][][]`, using a technique called "jagged arrays".

You'd create the base array much like you would any other array, except you don't specify the size of the last dimension:

```
int[][][] myArray = new int[5][5][];
```

Then, you add arrays to the 2-d array to store data:

```
myArray[0][0] = new int[4];
myArray[0][0][0] = 4;   
myArray[0][0][1] = 5;
myArray[0][0][2] = 6;
myArray[0][0][3] = 7;
```

Then, if you wanted to store 6 elements in (0,1), you could say

```
myArray[0][1] = new int[6];
// set values
```

And so on for each of the other cells.  You can also resize the arrays the same way as you normally would:

```
myArray[2][3] = Arrays.copyOf(myArray[2][3],myArray[2][3].length + 1);
```

Hope this helps.

## Edit

Following discussions in the comments, I came up with the following solution:

```
class MyContainer
{
    private Map<int, Map<int, List<string>>> data; //initialize in constructor

    public void setDataAt(int x, int y, List<string> value)
    {
        if (!data.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            data[x] = new HashMap<Map<int, Map<int, string>>();
        }
        if (!data[x].ContainsKey(y))
        {
            data[x] = new HashMap<int, string>();
        }
        data[x][y] = value;
    }
}
```

The important bit is checking at each level to ensure the data structure below exists, and creating it if it doesn't.  Of course, types can be changed, I used `HashMap` because I didn't know if datapoints will always be in order - and if you want to add by index, it's usually far easier than trying to use a `List<>`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there any way that I don't specify this `myArray[0][0] = new int[4];` because I need the 3rd dimension to add more values as they are available, ie something like `List.add(item)`

Comment: @herious If you don't know the number of data items you need to store, the best option us probably to use an array of lists: `List<?>[][]`. Note the wildcard, which is required by the compiler, ensuring the array only contains lists of the right type is up to you.

Comment: So if I define this List<String>[][][] list; how would I add items to the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd dimension respectively? like the add method?

Comment: @Herious, what do you mean? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Herious how many of the dimensions will you actually know in advance?  You might be better using something like a `List<List<List<int>>>`.

Comment: @RoadieRich I need a 3D list of String type, I tried to do this `List<List<List<String>>>` but I don't know how to add or retrieve the data from each spot in the array

Comment: For example the program read a string like this in a text file : (0 1 x y): array[0][1]: store x and y separately to use later

Comment: @Herious I'll update my answer, it's going to be slightly longer than a comment will allow.

Comment: @RoadieRich Thank you again for the answer, this may work for me but I recently just figured out that I just need to store a string with 2 or more substrings and then use charAt or substring to separate them

Answer (score 1):

In java, 2 D array is an array of array.

```
String [][]a = new String [3][];
```

You may or may not mention the the second index here, if your array size may vary, you can leave it blank.

```
a[0] ={"apple"};
a[1] ={"cat","dog","mouse"};
a[2] ={"hi","hello"};
```